# Creating an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create an array of structures containing some basic information.  My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} Customer;

int main(void) {

int i, customer_number, _zip, _accountId;
struct Customer customer_list[9];
char _firstName[30], _lastName[30], _street[35], _city[20], _state[3], _phone[15];


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        customer_number = 0;
        printf("Enter data for customer %d: \n", customer_number);
        printf("Enter First Last Phone: ");
        scanf("%s%s%s", &_firstName, &_lastName, &_phone);

        printf("\nEnter Address (Street City State ZIP): ");
        scanf("%s%s%s%d", &_street, &_city, &_state, &_zip);

        Customer customer_list[i] = {[i].firstName = _firstName}

    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like this should work, however I am getting an error saying " i must have constant value"  Can anyone push me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: Try changing `struct Customer customer_list` to just `Customer customer_list`.

Comment: It didn't seem to fix the main issue, but that is a good point.  I have already defined the structure earlier, so there's no need to do it again inside the main function, correct?

Comment: Yes, you don't need `struct Customer` in the last line of the for loop in main.

Comment: Don't use so many global variables — in fact, don't use any of them.  A variable called `i` should never be a global; the only one that might have some justification is the `customer_list`, and even that's debatable.

Comment: The line `struct Customer customer_list[i] = {[i].firstName = _firstName}` doesn't compile.  Even if the missing `;` is added, it won't compile.  But you don't want it to compile — you're defining a local array `customer_list` that (a) hides the global one you want to assign to and (b) goes out of scope on each iteration, thus throwing away the old data.  There isn't a type `struct Customer` (only the structure with typedef name `Customer`).  The array is variable size (a variable length array, or VLA); you can't initialize VLAs.

Comment: So variables used in multiple functions should be global then correct?

Comment: In general, no; you should pass them around as parameters.  However, sometimes, yes — for example, it would be a complete pain to have to pass `stdout` as a parameter everywhere you wanted to use it.  But avoid them whenever possible.  Indexes like `i` should never be global.  You should use `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)` in each loop, even if there are 3 consecutive loops in the function, for example.

Comment: Interesting, this is making more sense!  Why is it still giving me the original error however? (i must have constant value).  I have it defined how you suggested now: for(int i = 0, i <10, i ++)

Comment: In the updated line `Customer customer_list[i] = {[i].firstName = _firstName}`, you need to lose the `Customer` (you want to assign to an element of the `customer_list` defined outside the loop, not create an array inside the loop).  You then have to fix the value assign.  You can do it with a compound literal like: `customer_list[i] = (Customer){ .firstName = "Fred" };`, but I'm drawing a blank on why you can't write `_firstName` in place of `"Fred"`.  OTOH, you should not be using names starting with an underscore; you should regard them as reserved for use by 'the implementation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Customer customer_list[i] = {[i].firstName = _firstName}
```

This line needs to be

```
strcpy(customer_list[i].firstName, _firstName);
```

EDIT: assignment should be done by `strcpy()`

Comment: That needs to be a `strcpy()` — you can't just assign arrays.

Comment: Ahhh, since its a character array.

Comment: You are right assignment should be done by 'strcpy()'

Comment: How do I use strcpy in this scenario?  I am trying this: strcpy(customer_list[i].firstName[30], _firstName[30]); but it is giving me an error saying "expression must be pointer to complete object type" when referring to customer_list.

Comment: when you specify array index, you will get char from char arrays. So firstName[30] is a char while firstName is a char*. answer is: strcpy(customer_list[i].firstName, _firstName);